# BigQuery: private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated

Tags: google-bigquery

I have credential json file, copy pasted from some template:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "{{ project_id }}",
  "private_key_id": "{{ key.private_key_id }}",
  "private_key": "{{ key.secret }}",
  "client_email": "{{ key.client_email }}",
  "client_id": "{{ key.client_id }}",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "{{ key.cert_url }}"
}
```

it works properly for readonly bigquery access, but when i switch to another key, it shows error:

```
 Get "https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/PROJECT1/datasets/DATASET1/tables/TABLE1?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": private key should be a PEM or plain PKCS1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated
```

both json file have similar json structure, the only difference is the content of `private_key_id`, `private_key`, `client_email`, `client_id`, and `client_x509_cert_url`.

the code that are failing is:

```
type EnsureBigQueryTableExistsIn struct {
    DatasetId string
    TableName string
    Reseller  string
}

func EnsureBigQueryTableExists(in EnsureBigQueryTableExistsIn, bqClient *bigquery.Client) error {
    // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-table-exists
    ctx := context.Background()
    tableRef := bqClient.Dataset(in.DatasetId).Table(in.TableName)
    if _, err := tableRef.Metadata(ctx); err != nil {
        var e *googleapi.Error
        if errors.As(err, &e) {
            if e.Code != http.StatusNotFound {
                return fmt.Errorf("failed check table existence: %v", err)
            }
            // table not found, create it:
            // https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-create-table-cmek
            err := tableRef.Create(context.Background(), &bigquery.TableMetadata{
                Name: in.TableName,
                Schema: []*bigquery.FieldSchema{
                    {
                        Name: "email",
                        Type: bigquery.StringFieldType,
                    },
                    {
                        Name: "root",
                        Type: bigquery.StringFieldType,
                    },
                    {
                        Name: "sub",
                        Type: bigquery.StringFieldType,
                    },
                    {
                        Name: "ts",
                        Type: bigquery.IntegerFieldType,
                    },
                    {
                        Name: "kind",
                        Type: bigquery.StringFieldType,
                    },
                    {
                        Name: `createdAt`,
                        Type: bigquery.IntegerFieldType,
                    },
                },
            })
            if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("table creation failed: %v", err)
            }
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("failed check table existence: %v", err)
    }
    // table already exists, skip table creation
    return nil
}
```

when switching key to readonly account, it doesn't have the error above, but since it's readonly, there's error when creating table (obviously) `table creation failed: googleapi: Error 403: Access Denied: Dataset PROJECT1:DATASET1: Permission bigquery.tables.create denied on dataset PROJECT1:DATASET1 (or it may not exist)., accessDenied)`

How can I know which part that are problematic?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, because I was wrongly copy pasting downloaded json directly, I should replace `secret` to `private_key`

so instead of:

```
{
   "secret": ...
   ...
}
```

it should be:

```
{
  "private_key": ....
  ...
}
```